# Grow div height depending on its neighbour

Tags: html, css

I want to make a div grow its height depending of its neighbours height. The problem is I have to be able to give them a minimum height. (130px). I think it's a very basic problem but I don't get it, hope someone can help me.

Problem:

- div.guide-image and div.guide-descr should always have the same
  height
- div.guide (or its childs) should have a minimum height of 130px.

Following situation:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6f6nphru/)

***HTML***

```
<div class="guide">
    <div class="guide-image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/64/36" /></div>
    <div class="guide-descr">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </div>
</div>
```

***CSS***

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div.guide
{
    width: 800px;
}

div.guide-image
{
    float: left;
    width: 250px;

    background-color: #B0BAC9;
}

div.guide-image img
{
    display: block;
    margin: 40px auto;

    max-width: 90%;
    max-height: 80%;
}

div.guide-descr
{
    float: left;
    width: 550px;

    padding: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    background-color: #116FD1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `display` property instead of `float` can lead to your goal. Try this:

```
div.guide
{
    display:table;
    width: 800px;
}

div.guide-image
{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
div.guide-descr
{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Check the **[DemoFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6f6nphru/1/)**

Antoher way can be using `flexbox` method but chek if you can support that [Here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

```
div.guide
{
    display:flex;
    width: 800px;
}
```

Demo for Flex **[DemoFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6f6nphru/2/)**

Comment: Everyday you can learn something new, didn't even knew it was possible to give a div the table layout. Thank you @Danko

Comment: @JojoHav glad to help u.